# module 'matplotlib' has no attribute '_get_executable_info' when importing matplotlib.animation

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to import matplotlib.animation but for some reason it won't.
I did update matplotlib to the latest version using pip. I'm using python 3.7 in jupyter notebook

Here's the traceback

````
<ipython-input-237-b2ea7dba549a> in <module>()
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      2 import matplotlib.image as mpimg
----> 3 import matplotlib.animation
      4 import copy
      5 import glob, os

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in <module>()
    735 # Combine ImageMagick options with pipe-based writing
    736 @writers.register('imagemagick')
--> 737 class ImageMagickWriter(ImageMagickBase, MovieWriter):
    738     '''Pipe-based animated gif.
    739 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in wrapper(writerClass)
    118         def wrapper(writerClass):
    119             self._registered[name] = writerClass
--> 120             if writerClass.isAvailable():
    121                 self.avail[name] = writerClass
    122             return writerClass

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in isAvailable(cls)
    728     def isAvailable(cls):
    729         try:
--> 730             return super().isAvailable()
    731         except FileNotFoundError:  # May be raised by get_executable_info.
    732             return False

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in isAvailable(cls)
    425         Check to see if a MovieWriter subclass is actually available.
    426         '''
--> 427         return shutil.which(cls.bin_path()) is not None
    428 
    429 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/animation.py in bin_path(cls)
    722         binpath = super().bin_path()
    723         if binpath == 'convert':
--> 724             binpath = mpl._get_executable_info('magick').executable
    725         return binpath
    726 

AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute '_get_executable_info'```
````

Comment: This could be caused by a broken matplotlib install.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to install ImageMagick and reinstall matplotlib after that.

Comment: ImageMagick is no dependency of matplotlib. It needs to work without it being installed. So the key here was to reinstall matplotlib.